# In activity get old data in bundle

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, bundle

I create notification and add Intent to start Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PriceActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(ID_ORDER, idOrder);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("GCM Notification");
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Text"));
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

In activity **PriceActivity** get old data. This data was sended in past attempts.

Code get data Bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String idOrder = bundle.getString(GcmIntentService.ID_ORDER);
    Log.i("idOrder", idOrder);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: use different requrstCode when calling getActivity

Comment: Thanks. This helped.

Answer (score 2):

Android is reusing the old `PendingIntent`. To update the "extras", you need to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```